# Font rendering in XNA is getting low quality

Tags: text, xna, rendering, blurry

I am currently working in XNA 4.0 trying to render a font that I got. The font is rendered with this:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(this.font, this.text, new Vector2(10, 10), this.color);
```

But some of my letters gets blurry and low quality (See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QLYI.jpg))

I have tried to change the SamplerState of the GraphicDevice but that does not seem to improve anything.

-Update-
After testing one of the ideas were XNA would compress the text and in that case loosing quality i tried out to create my own font texture instead of generating one using a .spritefont. And then sending that into the contentloader, the results I managed to get was just slightly larger text but with the same artifacts.
See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25hQ6.jpg)

And I was now wondering if the problem still can have to do with compressing problems or if there could be another issue making the font get a lower quality in the program compared to using it ouside the program.
The way I am currently loading my font is using

```
font= ContentManager.Load<SpriteFont>(FontPath);
```

Comment: More information on this for you:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15469/how-do-i-get-beautiful-small-text-in-xna-without-using-external-libraries

Comment: Have you tried the instructions for making a texture font from rot13s answer? I did, and my font is sharp. Your 2nd image provided is a little small and looks like the original font to me.

Comment: I did try that and I have got a minor improvement but its still not sharp so I am currently looking at if there is any problem with my font

Comment: Even if you don't use any scaling, might this help? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering-for-sprite-scaling-in-xna-4-0

Comment: @Kai Hartmann Updated the second image to be a lot clearer with the new results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because XNA uses compression for spritefonts. The possible workarounds are:

- Use [Nuclex framework](http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/), which includes an alternative font importer;
- Make your own font texture, following the instructions from [Shawn Hargreaves's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/04/26/bitmap-fonts-in-xna.aspx);
- In your SpriteFont definition, double the size of generated font, then draw it at half its size.

Comment: Now that Shawn Hargreaves' linked software is gone (at least, I can't find it), is there a modern replacement to the second option?